# Create a new column of people not in another dataframe column grouped by 2 other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, dplyr, data-cleaning

I want to create an out_player_1 and out_player_2 column based on if the player name in Data frame 1 is not in the player name column of Data frame 2.
Plus, I want it grouped by team and date in Dataframe 1.

Basically, I want to say which player is out for a certain team on a certain date. Dataframe 1 is a complete dataframe and Dataframe 2 is a complete list of all the players on each team.

`dplyr` is preferred by the way. Speed is critical and I am more familiar with `dplyr` than `data.table`.

Dataframe 1

```
date      name   team   
1/1/16    Bill   Hawks  
1/1/16    Bob    Hawks
1/1/16    Matt   Hawks
1/1/16    George Hawks
1/2/16    Bill   Hawks  
1/2/16    Bob    Hawks
1/2/16    Matt   Hawks
1/2/16    Josh   Hawks
1/3/16    Josh   Hawks
1/3/16    Josh   Browns
1/3/16    Bill   Browns
1/3/16    Bob    Browns
1/3/16    George Browns
```

Dataframe 2

```
player team 
Bill   Hawks
Bob    Hawks
Matt   Hawks
George Hawks
Josh   Hawks
Bill   Browns
Bob    Browns
Matt   Browns
George Browns
Josh   Browns
```

Desired Dataframe

```
date      name   team   out_player_1 out_player_2
1/1/16    Bill   Hawks   Josh           NA
1/1/16    Bob    Hawks   Josh           NA
1/1/16    Matt   Hawks   Josh           NA
1/1/16    George Hawks   Josh           NA
1/2/16    Bill   Hawks   George         NA
1/2/16    Bob    Hawks   George         NA
1/2/16    Matt   Hawks   George         NA
1/3/16    Josh   Hawks   George         Josh
1/3/16    Bob    Hawks   George         Josh
1/3/16    Matt   Hawks   George         Josh
1/3/16    Josh   Browns  Matt           NA
1/3/16    Bill   Browns  Matt           NA
1/3/16    Bob    Browns  Matt           NA
1/3/16    George Browns  Matt           NA
```

Comment: Not quite clear (to me)

Comment: Try `left_join` - see http://stat545.com/bit001_dplyr-cheatsheet.html#left_joinsuperheroes-publishers

Comment: Does order matter to you? ie Is out_player_1 = George, out_player_2=Josh different from out_player_1 = Josh, out_player_2 = George?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: As I was working on the solution anyway: http://pastebin.com/Wnbj4wiA

Comment: wow C0bra, that worked perfectly. That was a simplified example. Could you explain it so I can apply it to my real problem.

Comment: I don't understand how this is left_join.